# How to use regex to split using last occurrence of forward slash in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have sample data as

```
with temp_table as 
(
select "/category/sub-category/title-of-the-page"  as pagename
union all
select "premier-league/splash"
union all
select "portal" 
union all 
select "news/1970/01/01/new-billion"
union all 
select "/premier-league/transfers/"
union all 
select "/premier-league/tfflive"
)

, clean_pagename as
(
select * , 
if (regexp_contains(pagename, "^/+" ) , regexp_extract(pagename, "^/+(.*)/?$") , pagename) as clean_page
from temp_table   
)

, dated_content as
(
select *, if (
regexp_contains(clean_page , "/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/") , 
regexp_replace(clean_page , "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]", "dated-content" ),
clean_page
) as  new_pagename
from clean_pagename 
)

,category_and_titles as
(
select *, split(new_pagename, "/")[offset(0)] as page_category,
coalesce(REGEXP_EXTRACT(new_pagename, r'/([^/]+)?$') , "no-title") as title,
regexp_replace(new_pagename, r'[^/]+$', "") as path
from dated_content 
)

select pagename,
page_category ,
path,
title
from category_and_titles
```

Here is what I am doing - I remove the first `/` in the string and replace date-content using a regex. Next I would like to extract 3 things

1. category - first section of the string before first `/`
2. path - that component of string from 0 until last `/` has been encountered
3. title - everything after last `/` in the string.

There are instances where `/` is not present at all (record #3). In this case I want all the 3 parts to be equal to original string.

For example - for string as `/premier-league/transfers/`, I would like my output to be -

```
category = "premier-league" , path = "premier-league/transfers/" , title = ""
```

My current code gives me results as

[image: output]

Whereas, I need -

[image: desired_output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much refactoring and leaving all your original logic intact - just do below changes for `category_and_titles` CTE

```
...
, category_and_titles AS (
  SELECT *, 
    SPLIT(new_pagename, "/")[OFFSET(0)] AS page_category,
    IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(new_pagename, r'/'), REGEXP_REPLACE(new_pagename, r'[^/]+$', ""), new_pagename)  AS path,
    IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(new_pagename, r'/'), COALESCE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(new_pagename, r'/([^/]+)?$'), "no-title"), new_pagename) AS title
  FROM dated_content 
)
...
```

with this minor change result will be as expected

[image]